# Can't post multiple variables using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, mysqli

I am only able to pass one of the variables in this code. If it looks like this I can only pass the `firstname` variable. When I accidently misspelled `fistname` (when I set the data to post) then only the `lastname` variable was passed. So I want to be able to post both variables that's my issue

```
var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "modify_profile.php",
    data: { firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname },
    success: function( data){             
    }
});
```

I have also tried to write:   data: {"firstname":firstname,"lastname":lastname}, but that didn't work either.

Here is the complete code. This is my file modify_profile.php. Everything happens in this file.

```
 <!Doctype HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title> Resor </title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <?php
        require("../db/connect.php");
        $email='test@gmail.com';


        // Hämtar all data från personen som är inloggad
        $sql="SELECT * from user WHERE email='$email'";
        $query=mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql);
        $result=mysqli_fetch_array($query);

        $firstname=$result['first_name'];
        $lastname=$result['last_name'];
        $password=$result['password'];



        // HERE IS WHERE FIRSTNAME IS CHANGED IN CASE IT HAS BEEN UPDATED.
            if( isset($_POST['firstname'])) 
            {

        $firstname=( $_POST['firstname']);
        $query=mysqli_query($dbcon, "UPDATE user SET first_name='$firstname' WHERE     email='$email'");
         $result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$query);
          if (!$result) {
              die("MySQL error ".mysqli_errno().": ".mysqli_error()."\n<br>When executing  <br>\n$query\n<br>");
          }

          }
//  HERE IS WHERE LASTNAME IS CHANGED IN CASE IT HAS BEEN UPDATED.
        if( isset($_POST['lastname']))
           {

        $lastname=( $_POST['lastname']);
        $query=mysqli_query($dbcon, "UPDATE user SET last_name='$lastname' WHERE email='$email'");
        $result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$query);
          if (!$result) {
              die("MySQL error ".mysqli_errno().": ".mysqli_error()."\n<br>When executing <br>\n$query\n<br>");
          }

          }



            echo "<p> Namn: $firstname $lastname  <span id=name> &Auml;ndra</span> </p>";






             ?>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">   </script>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){



                $('#name').on('click', function() {
                    var node = "<form action='modify_profile.php' method='post'><p>F&ouml;rnamn: <input type='text' name='firstname' id='firstname'value='<?=$firstname?>' ></p><p>Efternamn: <input type='text' name='lastname' id='lastname' value='<?=$lastname?>'></p><p>V&auml;nligen mata in ditt l&ouml;senord f&ouml;r att bekr&auml;fta &auml;ndringen.</p> <p> L&ouml;senord:<input type='password' name='password'  id='password'></p><input type='button' value='Spara &auml;ndringar' id='confirm_name'/><input type='button' value='Avbryt' id='cancel_name_change' /></form>";





                    $(this).parent().after(node);
                    $(this).parent().remove();

                }); 

                            //if the confirm button has been pressed
                $(document).on('click', '#confirm_name', function(){
                var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
                var lastname=$("#lastname").val();
                var password=$("#password").val();


                if(password!='<? echo "$password"; ?>'){
                alert("No changes has been made due to wrong password.");
                }
                else{
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "modify_profile.php",
                      data: {"firstname":firstname,"lastname":lastname},
                        success: function( data){     
                        }
                    }); 
                }
                });

                // if interrupted 

                $(document).on('click', '#cancel_name_change', function(){

                location.reload();

                });

                //slutparentes
            });
            </script>
            <?php require("../db/close.php")
            ?>
        </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: That's the right syntax. Did you try `print_r($_POST)` in your `modify_profile.php` file?

Comment: open the firebug console and check the sent parameter from the ajax request.

Comment: Maybe the problem comes from you php code, can you show us the code of modify_profile.php? (just the part where you get the variables)

Comment: [This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gKagv/) shows that the request itself works properly. It will of course give 404, as the php file is not found, but if you check the Network tab of the inspector in your browser, you will see that both values appear correctly. Something else happens there in your code, or the problem is in the PHP part.

Comment: I agree with the others.. Seems like the problem lies within modify_profile.php... Please share the code if you can...

Comment: Your code is absolutely correct, assuming the field IDs are correct. The only issue is the ugly use of spaces, e.g. after `(` - and that doesn't affect how the code works.

Comment: I have now. The array is empty.

Comment: Use like `
    data: { 'firstname': firstname, 'lastname': lastname },`

Comment: I have now posted the whole code. Sorry for the comments in swedish on the page. I will write comments where I get the variables Getz.

Comment: It's not the question, but your PHP code is very vulnerable to SQL injection... Use query parameters, or at least mysqli_escape_string.

Comment: Yes you are right Getz. That is something I will change later on.

Comment: You should really separate the code which call the ajax request and the code called in two separate php files. Just write php in the file which is requested, not html or javascript (except if you want to return html).

Comment: Are you actually displaying echoing the password to browser????

Comment: No I am going to change that Mchl. It was a fast solution when I was trying ajax.I will just use a query instead.

Comment: Well I prefere to have them in the same file Getz. That shouldn't be a problem or should it?